# Assigning a variable in jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, pandas

how to assign a variable `target` with the `Loan_Status` feature from `mydata` dataframe

```
target = mydata[]
```

Comment: `target = mydata['Loan_Status']`

Answer (score 0):

Check out how dictionary works in python: [Python dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

You probably want something like:

```py
target = mydata['Loan_Status']
```

If you are not sure, if `Loan_status` is the correct key, you can print out all keys with [DataFrame.keys()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.keys.html):

```py
print(mydata.keys())
```